# How to decrypt database activity events from AWS Aurora?

Tags: amazon-aurora

I have turned on database activity events which I think is some kind of log file on AWS Aurora. They are currently being passed through AWS kinesis into s3 via AWS Firehose. The log in s3 looks like this:

```
{"type":"DatabaseActivityMonitoringRecords","version":"1.0","databaseActivityEvents":"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","key":"AQIDAHhQgnMAiP8TEQ3/r+nxwePP2VOcLmMGvmFXX8om3hCCugE7IUxSH/eJBEKvnkYoNIqFAAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMQIX97gE5ioBR1+nnAgEQgDuDX2B2T7nOxjKDyL31+wHJb0pwkCeaU7CwA6BwIkiT7FmhMB71XgvCVrY9C9ABUtc1e5J7QIfsVB214w=="}
```

I think a KMS key is being used to encrypt that log file. How do I decrypt it? Is there working sample code somewhere? Also, more importantly, the Aurora database I'm using is a test database with no activity (no inserts, selects, updates). Why are there so many logs? Why are there so many `databaseActivityEvents`. They seem to be getting written to s3 every minute of the day.

Comment: How did you enable activity events? Does Aurora generate the kinesis stream or is that something you built on top of something that Aurora offers? Could not find any docs around the feature you are trying to use..

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.html

Comment: Ah postgres! I thought you were referring to aurora MySQL.

Comment: Any idea how to decrypt this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it uses RDS Activity stream KMS key (ActivityStreamKmsKeyId) for encrypting the log event and also base64 encoding. You will have to make use of AWS cryptographic SDKs to decrypt the key and the log event.

For reference see below their the sample java and python versions:

[Processing a Database Activity Stream using the AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/DBActivityStreams.html#DBActivityStreams.CodeExample)

In your firehose pipeline you can add transformation with Lambda step and do this decryption in your lambda function.

Why there are so many events in idle postgres RDS cluster? They are heartbeat events.

When you decrypt and take a look at the actual activity event json, it has **type** field which can be either be record or heartbeat. Events with type **record** are the user activity generated ones.